# Problems Updating/Editing records from VB.Net application to Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, sql-update, insert-update

Hi im having problems updating corrections from my VB.Net application to the Access Database. I get the following error:

"Syntax error in update statement" or "Data Mismatch error in criteria expression"

Here's the code below:

Public Function save1stsemester()
        'this code updates 1st semester records to database

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbcursor As Integer = 0
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim cmdUpdate As New OleDb.OleDbCommand


    Dim msg1 As String
    Dim style As MsgBoxStyle
    Dim result As MsgBoxResult
    Dim title, remarks As String

    Dim totalgrade As Integer = CInt(txtTotalMK.Text)
    Dim totalload As Integer = CInt(txtTotalLoad.Text)

    Dim gpadecimal As Decimal
    gpadecimal = CDec(lblGPA1.Text)

    title = "Success"
    style = MsgBoxStyle.Information

    Call allremarks() ' this function gathers all the remarks to a single variable.
    remarks = allremarks()

    Dim failflag As Boolean
    If checkflag100() = True Then 'True means all courses were passed then turn on Flag
        failflag = True
    Else
        failflag = False
    End If


    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        GoTo cont
    Else
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
            dbSource = "Data Source =C:\CGPA\e-CGPA Stat\e-CGPA Stat\bin\Debug\Scoredata.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
            conn.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
            conn.Open()

            da.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM 100Level1stSemester WHERE MatNO like '%" + cmbMATNO.Text + "%'")
            da.SelectCommand.Connection = conn

            Dim mycomand As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

            da.Fill(ds, "100Level1stSemester")

cont:       If cmbCourseLevel.SelectedItem = "100 Level" Then
                '  Try
                cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE 100Level1stSemester " & _
                "SET MatNo = '" & cmbMATNO.Text & "'" & _
                ", FName = '" & cmbStatFName.Text & "'" & _
                ", MName = '" & cmbStatInitial.Text & "'" & _
                ", SName = '" & cmbStatSname.Text & "'" & _
                ", STA110 = '" & txtGR1.Text & "'" & _
                ", MTH110 = '" & txtGR2.Text & "'" & _
                ", MTH112 = '" & txtGR3.Text & "'" & _
                ", ACC111 = '" & txtGR4.Text & "'" & _
                ", GST111 = '" & txtGR5.Text & "'" & _
                ", GST112 = '" & txtGR6.Text & "'" & _
                ", GST123 = '" & txtGR7.Text & "'" & _
                ", [STA110-SCORE] = '" & txtSC1.Text & "'" & _
                ", [MTH110-SCORE] = '" & txtSC2.Text & "'" & _
                ", [MTH112-SCORE] = '" & txtSC3.Text & "'" & _
                ", [ACC111-SCORE] = '" & txtSC4.Text & "'" & _
                ", [GST111-SCORE] = '" & txtSC5.Text & "'" & _
                ", [GST112-SCORE] = '" & txtSC6.Text & "'" & _
                ", [GST123-SCORE] = '" & txtSC7.Text & "'" & _
                ", [Tot-Grade-Point] = '" & totalgrade & "'" & _
                ", [Tot-Credit-Load] = '" & totalload & "'" & _
                ", [1stSemesterGPA] = '" & gpadecimal & "'" & _
                ", Remarks = '" & remarks & "'" & _
                ", Flag = '" & failflag & "'" & _
                " WHERE MatNo = '" & cmbMATNO.Text & "'"

                cmdUpdate.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
                cmdUpdate.Connection = conn
                cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmdUpdate.Dispose()

                conn.Close()

                msg1 = "100 Level 1st semester exam score and grades updated successfully."

                result = MsgBox(msg1, style, title)
                cmdVerifySem1.Enabled = False
                Grp1stSEM.Enabled = True

                'Catch
                MessageBox.Show("An error occured while updating the student's 100 Level scores! Duplicate entry was detected in the database. Ensure that the student's scores has not been entered before and try again.")
                'End Try
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

I have been advised to use parametrized query, which i dont know how to use.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You generally get a `Data Mismatch` error when you are trying to set a numeric column to a non numeric value or you are trying to join 2 tables on columns with different data types. You're updating here not joining so examine your built SQL statement and ensure that valid values are being put into each column. Given the reference to `Criteria` look especially at the value of `cmbMATNO.Text`

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty hard to read the command text you are using for your update because of how you have it written.  That is one good reason to use a parameterized query, but hardly the best reason.  Here is a sample using a parameterized query:

```
    Dim cmdText As String = "INSERT INTO Customer(Name, EmailAddress) VALUES (?,?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(cmdText, con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUserName.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text
```

Basically, you use ? in the string to represent the values you will be replacing with your variables/textbox values.  Then you add a parameter to your command for each one, in the same order they appear in your command string.  This makes it much easier to read the command string and verify proper syntax.  It also protects your database from injection.